# Check listener return value and do action is acceptable in laravel?

Tags: laravel, events, listener

I have a `Team` and it have `users`. If i remove user from team at the time i fire a event with `team and user` as parameter value and receive this in listener. If listener receive value correctly then `return status true` else `return status false`. if it return true then only can remove user from team. It implemented like below.

`TeamController` update method

```
$arr = event('team.user.removing', array(
                'team' => $team,
                'user' => $user,
            ));
if($arr['status']){
// remove user from team
}
else {
// not remove user from team
}
```

`EventServiceProvider` boot method

```
    parent::boot();
    Event::listen(
        'team.user.removing',
        'Listeners\TeamUserRemovingListener'
    );
```

`TeamUserRemovingListener` class

```
class TeamUserRemovingListener
{
    public function handle($team, $user)
    {
        if ($team && $user) {
            return ['status' => true];
        } else {
            return ['status' => false];
        }
    }
}
```

My question is if i check condition in `TeamController` like `$arr['status']` is acceptable or not? why? Because i get the response from listener. Is it ok?

Comment: Why are you using events/listeners to determine if a user can be removed from a team and not the built in [authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#introduction)? Your approach currently does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @Remul Actually I want to send notification to related team with user details. So I used event listener. But the thing I want to check team and user values are passed correctly to listener only you can remove user or else can’t.

Comment: @Remul how can we check event listener work correctly before remove user from team? If any effective way?

Comment: Are you got any answer? or solution?